# Charset UTF-8 not working on <?php contact form

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I am trying to make utf-8 work when receives the email.
When the form is filled up the characters shows as codes if is ç/Ç shows &$
Ex: Avan**ç**ado shows Avan**&$**ado

I Tried using the " header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8'); "
but still not working please help me thank you so much...

This is my code...

```
<?php

    //Get Data do Site
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $service = strip_tags($_POST['service']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $phoneconfirm = strip_tags($_POST['phoneconfirm']);
    $priority = strip_tags($_POST['priority']);
    $subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

        // Send Message
    header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
    mail( "THEEMAIL@GOES.HERE", "Via Website",
    "De: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Serviço: $service\n Telefone/Celular: $phone\n Ligar/Retornar: $phoneconfirm\n Prioridade: $priority\n Assunto: $subject\n Mensagem:\n $message",
    "Para: WebSite");
    ?>
```

Comment: Your question needs better intro.

Comment: Show us the HTML form, where the name, email, service, phone, phoneconfirm.... is getting set. Also show us the `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML (it must be there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting the mail header there, you are setting the http header. This function `header` is sending a raw HTTP header, it isn't doing anything for the email you are sending

```
   header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

You need to add the header *"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"* (for HTML Email bodies)  or *"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"* (for Plain Text Email bodies)  to your `mail` function. Like this.

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

Additionally, for email, each lines should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n) instead of merely using a linefeed (\n). A fully example end result might look more so like this:

```
<?php

    $crlf = "\r\n";

    //Get Data
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $service = strip_tags($_POST['service']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $phoneconfirm = strip_tags($_POST['phoneconfirm']);
    $priority = strip_tags($_POST['priority']);
    $subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

    // Parse/Format/Verify Data
    $to      = "THETOEMAIL@GOES.HERE";
    $from    = 'THEFROMEMAIL@GOES.HERE';
    $subject = "Via Website";
    $message = "De: $name$crlf E-Mail: $email$crlf Serviço: $service$crlf
         Telefone/Celular: $phone$crlf Ligar/Retornar: $phoneconfirm$crlf 
         Prioridade: $priority$crlf Assunto: $subject$crlf Mensagem:$crlf 
         $message";

    // Setup EMAIL headers, particularly to support UTF-8
    // We set the EMAIL headers here, these will be sent out with your message
    // for the receiving email client to use.
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from  . $crlf .
               'Reply-To: ' . $from  . $crlf .
               'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .  $crlf .
               'Para: WebSite'  .  $crlf .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Then we pass the headers into our mail function
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Reference:

- [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: sorry but i did not got what you said could you be a little bit more specific like explain it more what you did on my code please

Comment: Note: This answer is specifying `text/html` as the header type, but the actual message body text is not HTML. You actually want `text/plain` in the `Content-Type` header. But in general, I would suggest avoiding building headers yourself; it is prone to security issues, and it's difficult to maintain. Use a decent library instead.

Comment: Bubba i have a problem when the email is sent now the headers are all in one line it need to be in another line each function i setted in $message

Comment: this code works perfectly but all the information got from the from is all in one line and when the subject its supose to get from the subject form not from the form $subject = "Via Website";

Comment: It is all in one line because you are telling the email client it is Content-Type: text/html instead of Content-Type: text/plain. You also need to use CRLF. You can make the subject whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it work in my case (Serbian, Croatian, Bosnian, ...):

in HTML page:
In header of yours email-form.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-UTF-8">
```

and in the "form":

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="http://yourdomain.com/e-mail.php" accept-charset='UTF-8' >
```

in PHP-mailer:

```
// create email headers
       $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
       'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
       'Para: WebSite'  .  "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usging a framework like Swift Mailer to send the email messages, instead of creating your own email headers.
That might solve the charset problem as well.

http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` function is for sending HTTP headers to the web browser that is loading the page. It does not have any effect at all on email content send via `mail()`.

In order to send mail headers using `mail()` you need to build them manually in the correct format.

This can be tricky to get right, and can make for very messy code, so I would suggest that instead you consider using a decent mailer class such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), either of which will allow you to specify mail headers in a much simpler way.

With PHPMailer, for example, you code could look something like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Body = "......";
$mail->Subject = "....";
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";    //see, very easy in phpMailer!
$mail->Send();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: phpmailer i cannot use it could you please get my code and change what it needs so i can just copy from here to put on mine's please? i am not getting at all sorry

Comment: @PatrickSterza - added the URL for PHPMailer to the answer. (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

If you won't like to use external class, may follow example in [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Basically, you just need to add UTF-8 to your mail header (not browser header).

```
 $headers    = array
    (
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
        'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
        'Message-ID: ',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion(),
        'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
    );

    mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($arr['subject']) . '?=', $arr['message'], implode("\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think** that is not a problem with the email, is a problem with the string characters contained in the `$_POST` variables!

When you send those strings from the HTML form to your PHP they are not encoded with UTF8.

Your HTML must have `<meta charset="utf-8">` and when the HTML renders from the PHP, that PHP must have `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');`.

Like this:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
?>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <meta charset="utf8">
    ...
<body>

<form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    ...

    Service:
    <input type="text" name="service" />
    ...

    <submit button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax for your fields. I had the exact same issue when I was trying to send French accents:

```
$variable = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['variable'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

The above takes the form field and places it into a variable encoded correctly as UTF-8.

For your example, I have changed it accordingly, so give this a go:

```
<?php

$name           = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$email          = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$service        = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['service'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$phone      = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['phone'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$phoneconfirm   = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['phoneconfirm'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$priority       = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['priority'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$subject        = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['subject'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$message        = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

// Send Message
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
mail( "THEEMAIL@GOES.HERE", "Via Website",
"De: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Serviço: $service\n Telefone/Celular: $phone\n Ligar/Retornar: $phoneconfirm\n Prioridade: $priority\n Assunto: $subject\n Mensagem:\n $message",
"Para: WebSite");

?>
```

Hope this helps you out!

Good luck,
Mikey.

Comment: sorry buddy it did not work well when i clicked the button send wouldn't even send =(

Comment: @PatrickSterza That's because there was an error. Try it now. I have updated the code!

Comment: still not sending when i click send wont load the contact.php page that is this code.. Mines works but its not showing the characters like çÇ áà é and etc...

Comment: @PatrickSterza What happens? Any errors shown? I'm gonna need more than that. I took your exact code and just replaced the vars with these newly escaped ones. Do you have Firebug for Firefox? Use the NET tab on that to see what variables get passed through?

Comment: OMG my send button its not sending, i click send message and it does nothing what did i do?

Comment: Just a moment whilst I harness my psychic powers...mmm...mmm... Nope! It didn't work. I kid I kid! Your best bet is to learn how to use the basics of Firebug. It's totally free and you'll really be doing yourself a disservice not using it. Without it, I don't know where I'd be! Download it and try it out.

Comment: my script form is not working i did not change nothing when i click send its supose to load the page contact.php but not loading nothing and when my script is empty when i click send it shows the messages errors http://patricksterza.com/syshouse/contato.html try it your self (nome = name - email - serviços you can select any one - put ths number 92225539 - put sim or nao means yes or no selet the priority put any thing you want the assunt means subject then the message and then you tell me what happens

Comment: now it worked because i added the function ($variable = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['variable'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));) that you posted above

Comment: now you know what still not working the utf-8 with your code =(

Comment: It sounds like you have some other issues going on. I would really check out what's happening bit by bit.