# How to enable UTF-8 character encoding in a php formmail

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8, formmail

This is the code:

```
    <?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
    mail("my@email.com", "Note To Self", $_POST["message"], "From: my@email.com");
    header( "Location: sent.html" );
}
?>
```

English characters are working fine but Chinese, Japanese and Korean come out in the email like this:

ãƒ ã‚³
çŒ«
ê³ ì–‘ì ´

Based on this topic: [Charset UTF-8 not working on <?php contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765539/charset-utf-8-not-working-on-php-contact-form) I added content type and character set:

```
<?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
    mail("my@email.com", "Note To Self", $_POST["message"], "From: my@email.com", "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    header( "Location: sent.html" );
}
?>
```

but now I don't receive the emails at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now. Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

```
<?php

$headers = 'From: my@email.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

if($_POST["message"]) {
    mail( "my@email.com", "Note To Self", $_POST["message"], $headers );
    header( "Location: sent.html" );
}
?>
```